# How to rotate text (div) in a perfect circle?

Tags: html, css, transform

I'm trying to rotate large glyphicon arrow around my donut form chart. I know the transform: rotate(360deg), and I've been using it, the thing is, the div that im trying to circle is not simetrical, therefore it goes out of bounds.

Take a look:

[image: Screenshot]

I also tried to make a keyframes for every 25%, but then the arrow stops on every 1/4 of the circle.

This is how it spins a 360deg circle:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiXwA.jpg

I want it to be exactly on the edge like on the start and not go into the chart.

Comment: Use the `transform-origin` property. Where is your code?

Comment: You should have posted it as an answer cause that was exactly what i needed, thank you for being able to understand me from half word.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using this `animation` from [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css):

```js
function animateit(){
var d = document.getElementById("animationSandbox");
d.className += " rotateIn";

}
```

```css
.site__title {
    color: #f35626;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(92deg,#f35626,#feab3a);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
}
.wrap {
    max-width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
span#animationSandbox {
    display: block;
}

/* the animation that you are looking for */
@keyframes rotateIn {
  from {
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -200deg);
  }

  to {
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 200deg);
  }
}

.rotateIn {
  animation: rotateIn 2s 5;
}
/* add the above animation to you css an give it to the elemnt you want to animate */
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <span id="animationSandbox" style="display: block;" class=""><h1 class="site__title mega">Animate.css</h1></span>
  </div>

<button onclick="animateit();">see animation</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

That donut looks like a perfect cercle to me, I think all you need to do is apply the follwing CSS to your arrow :

```
.my-arrow {
    padding-top: 2px; /* or just add 2px if you already have a padding setting */
}
```